# EE 2.8.1 mailing list This form has expired

Tags: forms, mailinglist

when SOME people try and add their email to the mailing list they get this error:

The following errors were encountered

This form has expired. Please refresh and try again.
Return to Previous Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = 'y';
```

to your config.php and you're done.

Comment: This disables csrf protection on the entire site for one  issue. I wouldn't say this is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

ExpressionEngine uses an anti [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) technique where it assigns a value to a hidden field (i believe the field name is `csrf_token` (`XID` in version < 2.8.0) and assigns the same value to a session. At form processing stage it compares the two and if they dont match the form returns an error. I believe the error you are getting is the one that gets returned when this happens.

If the visitor is getting this error, the form might be cached at the server / network level, delivering them a stale CSRF token. Are all of the affected users on the same network? Corporate firewalls could be delivering stale pages, for instance.

Comment: some different users on different networks.  It isn't happening to me but is for some.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's what I have described above. I have had the same problem very recently with one of my clients.

Comment: I do not see a solution in your comment above.  What did you do to fix it?

Comment: There should be a setting in config.php file. Something like 'csfr protection, true' - change it to false.